# pageToOverride Chrome extension - set default tab opening chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome url overrides for open myPage.html when users open new tab.

The problem is that if I open chrome, it loads the default tab and not  myPage.html.
myPage.html is only opened if I click new tab botton.

In my manifest I have:

```
 "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "pageToOverride": "myPage.html"
  },
```

What I have to change?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

From the [Override Pages documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html):

> For `pageToOverride`, substitute one of the following:
>
> - `bookmarks`
> - `history`
> - `newtab`

so:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
   "newtab": "myPage.html"
},
```